# Translating code using subprocess in Python 2.7 to Python 2.3

Tags: python, stdout

I'm writing a python program that will spawn a subprocess to basically clone a log file. I have working code in 2.7, but because of vendor restrictions, I am forced to use Python 2.3, so using the subprocess module is *out of the question*.

I need help translating this:

```
self.FILE_OUT =  open(self.file2write,"a" )
self.FILE_IN=subprocess.Popen( self.file2process,
               stdout=self.FILE_OUT,
               bufsize=0,
               shell=True)
```

into 2.3 code.

I'm confused as to how to do the `stdout=self.FILE_OUT`.

Comment: The documentation seems pretty clear.  http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/module-popen2.html  Should have all the information you need.  What part is confusing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing, but the old way of executing commands was to use `os.popen`. It works like this:

```
>>> echo_stdout = os.popen('echo foo', 'r')
>>> echo_stdout.read()
'foo\n'
```

There are other versions of `popen` in the `os` module that do things like return a 2-tuple containing `stdin` and `stdout`, or a 3-tuple containing `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`. See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen) for more details, and let me know if this doesn't help.

Here's an example of how to use `popen2`:

```
>>> cat_stdin, cat_stdout = os.popen2('cat')
>>> cat_stdin.write('foo\n')
>>> cat_stdin.close()
>>> cat_stdout.read()
'foo\n'
```

Comment: I'm ok with that part, it's the getting STDOUT into a file that I'm not sure about.